# Please advise why my text is not aligned?

Tags: string, assembly, x86-64, padding, text-alignment

This question is about *chain alignment*.
Program the function `void align_str(char \*output, char \*in, unsigned int size, int align)` which equals the input string according to the following rules and the result of the delivery for the memory location specified.
Valued by the output argument.

- The output length of chain is the same size.
- Argument alignment specifies the alignment as follows: 0 = left, 1 = center, 2 = right, for other
  value, the result is undefined.
- In case of left alignment, the first character is never a space.
- In the case of right alignment, the last character is never a space.
- The chain is completed with gaps to the required length.
- In the case of center alignment, spaces are filled equally at the beginning and end of the chain.
- Assume that the input contains only ASCII table characters from the range 0x20 to 0x7e (inclusive).
- If all conditions cannot be met (e.g. the length of the text without opening and closing spaces is longer
  than size), the result is undefined.

```
 align_str:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push rbx
    push r12
    push r13

    ; Save registers on the stack

    mov r12, rdi ; r12 = output string
    mov r13, rsi ; r13 = input string
    mov ebx, edx ; ebx = output string size
    mov edi, ecx ; edi = alignment

    ; Calculate the length of the input string

    xor ecx, ecx ; ecx = 0
    xor edx, edx ; edx = 0

    strlen_loop:
        mov al, byte [r13 + rcx]
        cmp al, 0
        je end_strlen
        inc edx
        inc ecx
        jmp strlen_loop

    end_strlen:

    ; Calculate the number of spaces needed for alignment

    mov eax, ebx ; eax = size
    sub eax, edx ; eax = size - input string length
    jle align_done ; if less than or equal to 0, skip alignment

    cmp ebx, 0 ; check if output string size is greater than 0
    jle align_done ; if not, skip alignment

    pad_spaces:
        mov ebx, eax ; ebx = number of spaces to pad
        cmp edi, 0 ; check alignment
        je align_left
        cmp edi, 1
        je align_center
        cmp edi, 2
        je align_right
        ; Invalid alignment value
        jmp align_done

    align_left:
        jmp pad_left
    align_center:
        shr ebx, 1 ; divide by 2
        jmp pad_center
    align_right:
        jmp pad_right

    pad_right:
        mov rdx, r12 ; rdx = output string
        add rdx, rax ; rdx = output string + number of spaces to pad on the right
        mov byte [rdx], 0 ; null-terminate
        mov rdx, r12 ; rdx = output string
        mov rcx, r13 ; rcx = input string
        xor eax, eax ; eax = 0
        pad_right_loop:
            mov al, byte [rcx]
            mov byte [rdx], al
            inc rdx
            inc rcx
            cmp byte [rcx - 1], 0 ; check if we reached the end of the input string
            jne pad_right_loop
        xor ecx, ecx ; ecx = 0
        pad_right_center_loop:
            mov al, ' ' ; space character
            mov byte [rdx], al
            inc rdx
            inc ecx
            cmp ecx, ebx ; compare with the number of spaces to pad on the right
            jl pad_right_center_loop
        jmp align_done

    pad_center:
        mov rdx, r12 ; rdx = output string
        add rdx, rbx ; rdx = output string + number of spaces to pad
        mov byte [rdx], 0 ; null-terminate
        mov rdx, r12 ; rdx = output string
        mov rcx, r13 ; rcx = input string
        xor eax, eax ; eax = 0
        pad_center_loop:
            mov al, byte [rcx]
            mov byte [rdx], al
            inc rdx
            inc rcx
            cmp byte [rcx - 1], 0 ; check if we reached the end of the input string
            jne pad_center_loop
        xor ecx, ecx ; ecx = 0
        pad_center_right_loop:
            mov al, ' ' ; space character
            mov byte [rdx], al
            inc rdx
            inc ecx
            cmp ecx, ebx ; compare with the number of spaces to pad
            jl pad_center_right_loop
        jmp align_done

    pad_left:
        mov rdx, r12 ; rdx = output string
        add rdx, rbx ; rdx = output string + number of spaces to pad on the left
        mov byte [rdx], 0 ; null-terminate
        mov rdx, r12 ; rdx = output string
        mov rcx, r13 ; rcx = input string
        xor eax, eax ; eax = 0
        pad_left_loop:
            mov al, byte [rcx]
            mov byte [rdx], al
            inc rdx
            inc rcx
            cmp byte [rcx - 1], 0 ; check if we reached the end of the input string
            jne pad_left_loop
        jmp align_done

    align_done:
        pop r13
        pop r12
        pop rbx
        leave
        ret
```

And this function I call from C:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
extern void align_str(char *output2, char *input2, unsigned int size, int alignment); 

int main() { 
  char input2[] = "Hello"; 
  char output2[10]; 
  unsigned int size = sizeof(output2); 
  int alignment = 1; 

  align_str(output2, input2, size, alignment); 
} // added by edit
```

Comment: Manipulating bytes, strings, arrays of bytes can be done in any language.  There's no reason to "think in assembly" to figure out the algorithms for this.  Do it in a language you know (preferably C) and when it is working, then all you have to do is transcribe your working C code into assembly, which means handling variables, for-loops, if-then, pointers, etc.. so you can do the same in assembly as the working C code.

Comment: It looks like "chain" just a mis-translation of "string" from another language.  In English we use "string" to describe an array of characters.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>    cmp edi, 0 ; check alignment
>    je align_left
>    cmp edi, 1
>    je align_center
>    cmp edi, 2
>    je align_right
>    ; Invalid alignment value
>    jmp align_done
>
> align_left:
>    jmp pad_left
> align_center:
>    shr ebx, 1 ; divide by 2
>    jmp pad_center
> align_right:
>    jmp pad_right
> ```

### What is alignment?

Left-aligning some string in a buffer means that the padding goes on the right, and right-aligning some string in a buffer means the padding goes on the left. Your code does it the other way round and does not implement it correctly. eg. *pad_right* begins writing spaces behind a terminating zero. Those spaces will never show up!

#### Left-alignment

```
Input:  [My name0]                   Length is 7 (calculated)
Output: [.....................]      Size is 21 (provided)

Padding is Size - 1 - Length = 21 - 1 - 7 = 13
Output: [My name             0]
                <-----13---->
```

#### Center-alignment

```
Input:  [My name0]                   Length is 7 (calculated)
Output: [.....................]      Size is 21 (provided)

Padding is (Size - 1 - Length) / 2 = (21 - 1 - 7) / 2 = 6
Output: [      My name       0]
         <--6->       <--7-->
```

#### Right-alignment

```
Input:  [My name0]                   Length is 7 (calculated)
Output: [.....................]      Size is 21 (provided)

Padding is Size - 1 - Length = 21 - 1 - 7 = 13
Output: [             My name0]
         <-----13---->
```

> • In case of left alignment, the first character is never a space.

> • In the case of right alignment, the last character is never a space.

Should the input contain one or more space characters on its extremities, the task wants you to remove those:

```
Input:  [  An extra example    0]    Length is 16 (calculated)
```

Although here the calculated StrLen is 22, discarding the leading and trailing spaces leads to a length of 16. Also the characters that you will be copying now begin at `RSI + 2` (because of the 2 leading spaces).

Good luck!

Comment: please help me how to solve it